# Returning int value from @html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

Actually I have some problem which happened because of lack of my knowledge in ASP.NET - MVC 4.
What I am trying to do is getting the selected value from the drop down and return it to the controller (as integer). What makes me more confuse is the other DropDownList which are returning string Value is working fine.

My model :

```
public partial class PRODUCT
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_NAME { get; set; }
    public int CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }
    public string LANGUAGE { get; set; }
}

public partial class PRODUCT_CATEGORY
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CATEGORY_NAME { get; set; }
    public string LANGUAGE { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller : 
//populating ViewBag

```
ListProductCategory = new List<PRODUCT_CATEGORY>();
ListProductCategory = db.PRODUCT_CATEGORY.ToList();

IList<PRODUCT_CATEGORY> prodCategories = db.PRODUCT_CATEGORY.ToList();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListCategory =
     from c in prodCategories
     select new SelectListItem
     {
      Text = c.CATEGORY_NAME,
       Value = c.ID.ToString()
     };

ViewBag.ProductCategoryData = selectListCategory;
```

//create action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PRODUCT product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.PRODUCTs.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(product);
}
```

My View :

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CATEGORY_ID)
 </div>

 <div class="editor-field">            
   @Html.DropDownList("ProductCategories", new  SelectList(ViewBag.ProductCategoryData, "Value", "Text"))          
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CATEGORY_ID)
 </div>
```

The DropDown lsit is populated but the value of ProductCategories not being returnd, its  returning 0 instead of the value.

Please help ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What other dropdownlists are returning strings? I bet the string they are returning is part of the model. Your model doesn't have a `ProductCategories` property. Try changing:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductCategories", new  SelectList(ViewBag.ProductCategoryData, "Value", "Text"))
```

To:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CATEGORY_ID", new  SelectList(ViewBag.ProductCategoryData, "Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: it works! thanks a lot. at first I thought the name in the first parameter is just for reference, so i just put anything i like.looks like there is a very long way to go in this ASP.NET for me.a million thanks for the helps. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try it

Add extra property in your model

```
public partial class PRODUCT
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_NAME { get; set; }
    public int CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }
    public string LANGUAGE { get; set; }
    **public int SelectedCATEGORY_ID { get; set; }**
}


@Html.DropDownListFor(**model=>model.SelectedCATEGORY_ID** , new  SelectList(ViewBag.ProductCategoryData, "Value", "Text"))
```

Now you can get the dropdown selected value in the SelectedCATEGORY_ID property .

---

or

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(**model=>model.CATEGORY_ID ** , new  SelectList(ViewBag.ProductCategoryData, "Value", "Text"))  


    Now you can get the dropdown selected value in the CATEGORY_ID property .
```

Comment: Model updated and HtmlDropDownList modified but i got an error saying "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type while applying Html part. Is there other thing should I change?

Comment: Change DropDownList to DropDownListFor